# Convert a CSV file with embedded commas into a bash array by line efficiently

Tags: perl, bash, shell

Normally, I do something like

```
IFS=','
columns=( $LINE )
```

where $LINE is a line from a csv file I'm reading.

However, how do I handle a csv file with embedded commas? I have to handle several hundred gigs of file so everything needs to be done quickly, i.e., no multiple readings of a line, definitely no loops (last time I tried that slowed it down several factors).

The general structure of the code is as follows

```
FILENAME=$1
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    IFS=","
    columns=( $LINE )
    # affect columns changes here
    newline="${columns[*]}"
    echo "$newline"
done
```

Preferably, I need something that goes

```
FILENAME=$1
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    IFS=","
    # code to tell bash to ignore if IFS is within an open quote
    columns=( $LINE )
    # affect columns changes here
    newline="${columns[*]}"
    echo "$newline"
done
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Otherwise, I'll probably switch to using another language to handle this stuff.

Comment: You definitely want to use another language for this task.

Comment: `read` in a shell script is absurdly slow.  It will execute a system call to `read` for every byte of input!  This is not a good way to process several hundred gigabytes of data.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I just found out the hard way after testing on some sample data. My current method will take me 45 days to finish processing the data. I'm switching to a C like language. Might be time to learn Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably *embedded commas* is just the first obvious problem that you encountered while parsing those CSV files.

Future problems that might popped are:

- **embedded newline** separator characters
- **embedded utf8 chars**
- special treatment for **whitespaces**, **empty fields**, **spaces around commas**, **undef values**

I generally tend to follow the philosophy that *If there is a (reputable) module that parses some 
format you have to parse, use it instead of making a homebrew*

I don't think there is such a thing for bash, but there are some for **Perl**. I'd go for [**`Text::CSV_XS`**](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-0.94/CSV_XS.pm). Being written in C I expect it to be very fast.

Comment: Good point. I initially just wanted a quick and dirty way to process the majority of this data into a form feedable to an engine, but unfortunately it was dirtier than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but it's a possible approach.

Find a character that never occurs in the input file. Use a C program that parses the CSV file and prints lines to standard output with a different delimiter. Writing that program is left as an exercise, but I'm sure there's CSV-parsing C source code out there. Pipe the output of the C program into your script.

For example:

```
FILENAME=$1
new_c_program $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    IFS="|"
    # code to tell bash to ignore if IFS is within an open quote
    columns=( $LINE )
    # affect columns changes here
    newline="${columns[*]}"
    echo "$newline"
done
```

A minor point: I'd pick a name other than `$newline`; `newline` suggests an end-of-line marker rather than an entire line.

Another minor point: you have a ["Useless Use Of `cat`"](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) in the code in your question. You could replace this:

```
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    ...
done
```

by this:

```
while read LINE
do
     ...
done < $FILENAME
```

But if you replace `cat` by the hypothetical C program I suggested, you still need the pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the cat tip. Didn't know that. Tip of the hat.

Comment: Incidentally, the example code replacement doesn't work http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-11/msg00026.html

Comment: @saccharine: Ah, yes, you're right (I should have tried it before posting). Quoting the linked message: "You are not allowed to put redirections in front of a compound command
(such as while).  Redirections must always appear at the end of a compound
command.

Redirections can appear anywhere within a *simple* command only."

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed or something similar to convert the commas within quotes to some other sequence or punctuation. If you don't care about the stuff in quotes then you do not even need to change them back. You can do this on the whole file:

```
sed 's/\("[^,"]*\),\([^"]*"\)/\1;\2/g' input.csv > intermediate.csv
```

or on each line:

```
line=$(echo $line | sed 's/\("[^,"]*\),\([^"]*"\)/\1;\2/g')
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what the sed command is doing? I'm not too familiar with using reg ex, and your sequence is confusing me. I'm having a hard time parsing it even with the wiki page open. This seems like the simplest answer, but it adds an extra readthrough of the line. Can I have it run somehow at the same time the columns=( $LINE ) is going on?